# OpenHFT Chronicle Queue Version 4 - nextSynchronous?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

In version 3 of OpenHFT's Chronicle Queue there is an API call on ExcerptAppender (`nextSynchronous(boolean`)) to request that the contents of the queue be forced to be written to disk (`fsync'd`)when the next excerpt is finished.  I don't see a similar call in version 4.  Is it possible to achieve the same effect with version 4?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. If you need guarenteed writes we suggest acknowledged replication.

I suggest you add it as a github issue, however I can't say when this will be added.

Comment: Ok, understood, but then for now we need to stay with version 3.  Is there any forum these days for reporting issues with chronicle version 3?  I have a stand-alone test that illustrates a problem with entries being lost on block roll-over.

Comment: @PaulBandler You can report these on Stackoverflow however we don't provide free support for version 3.